# How to eliminate recurring authorization prompts for Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have Google Apps Script projects related to Telegram bot. The script is triggered mainly through doPost requests from telegram. I created a separate project in Google Cloud and linked it to a script. At the first launch and then everything works fine, but after exactly a week, the script again requests permission to run. Ie, the bot stops and does not work until I log into the project and issue permission for execution again.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem? How can I fix this constant request for permission to run the script?

I would be grateful for any help in solving this problem with constant requests for permissions

I have tried to configure permissions and OAuth in different ways, but so far it has not yielded any results.
About three days ago I tried two methods, but today the bot stopped again - these methods turned out to be non-working.

Comment: I think I read that on unpaid accounts things like that occur with web apps, but I'm not sure which is kind  of a nuissance